# Chrome plugin - detect if an anchor tag was clicked

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension that needs to determine whether an anchor tag on the current page has been clicked or whether the page was simply refreshed.

All this code goes in my content script so that it executes each time the page is refreshed.

I have tried using

```
if($('a').data('clicked'));
```

but for some reason that is returning `undefined`.

I can't use

```
$('a').click(function(){...});
```

because I need to have an `else` clause in my code that executes if a link was not clicked.

To sum up: I want an `if/else` statement in my Chrome extension using jQuery that executes code if a link was clicked and also if it was not clicked.

Comment: So you need to have code that executes continously (the `else` clause) until a link is clicked?

Comment: No, I need specific code that executes when the page is refreshed without a link being clicked - that is, when the refresh button is clicked or when a URL is typed into the navigation bar. And then I need specific code that executes when the page is refreshed when a link is clicked. Basically, one or the other - never both and never neither. Because the page will be refreshed - and when it is, I need to determine how it was refreshed. That is the purpose of my code. But I can't get the if statement to work.

Answer (score 1):

You could bind a click listener, set a flag, and then bind to the `beforeunload` event which will be called before a refresh.

```
var clicked = false;

$('a').click(function(){
    clicked = true;
);

$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {

    if (clicked == true) {
      // link was clicked... execute code
    } else { 
      // no link clicked... execute other code
    }

});
```